# fscanf_s not works properly in Winserver2008 VS2013 64bit

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, windows-server-2008-r2

When we use fscanf_s method in Visual studio 2013 (C++ Console application), Os- Winsever2008  (64 bit), the file pointer reads the data one or 2 bytes in advance.
Eg: While reading text file , the second line of the file is "Administartor", but the fscanf_s() returns the word as "dministrator".
Please help me to correct this issue.
The code is working fine with WIndows XP 32 bit using Visual studio 2008.

```
FILE* pFile;
pFile = NULL;
string strFile = "E:\\10_Products.lrf";
fopen_s(&pFile, strFile.c_str(), "r");
char szTemp[256];
string strTemp = "";
if (NULL != pFile)
{   
    while (!feof(pFile))
    {
        nRet = fscanf_s(pFile, "%s", szTemp);
        if (EOF == nRet)
        {
            cout << "EOF detected";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The format of 10_Products.lrf file is given below.

```
[OPERATOR_LEVEL]
Administrator
```

Comment: sample code
   
     FILE* pFile;
     pFile = NULL;
     string strFile = "E:\\10_Products.lrf";
     fopen_s(&pFile, strFile.c_str(), "r");
     char szTemp[256];
     string strTemp = "";
     if (NULL != pFile)
     { 
      while (!feof(pFile))
      {
       nRet = fscanf_s(pFile, "%s", szTemp);
       if (EOF == nRet)
       {
        cout << "EOF detected";
       }

     }
     return 0;
    }

Comment: You should edit your post instead of adding this as comment

Comment: [`while(!feof())` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: If use fscanf this code works properly.

Comment: For fscanf_s it shows this issue, pls help to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

From the docs on fscanf_s(), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc.aspx:

```
The main difference between the secure functions (with the _s suffix) and the older functions is that the secure functions require the size of each c, C, s, S and [ type field to be passed as an argument immediately following the variable. For more information, see scanf_s, _scanf_s_l, wscanf_s, _wscanf_s_l and scanf Width Specification.
```

And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx:

```
Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or [. The buffer size is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable. For example, if reading a string, the buffer size for that string is passed as follows:

char s[10];

scanf("%9s", s, 10);
```

So you should call it like so:

fscanf_s(fp,"%80s",cmd, sizeof(cmd));